# Compress PHP array of characters to shorter array with a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this:

`array('A','B','C','F','a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','o','q','!','?','0','1','2','3','4','9')`

How can I convert this to:

`array('A-C','F','a-f','h-l','o','q','!','?','0-4','9')`

There will only be standard ASCII characters - nothing fancy. Every character can only appear once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to compare the current character to the incremented value of the previous one. If the current character is not consecutive, then the increment the range index.

```
$ranges = [];
$i = -1;
$previous = '';
foreach ($characters as $char) {
    $test = $previous;
    $i += (++$test == $previous || $test != $char);
    $ranges[$i] = isset($ranges[$i]) ? $ranges[$i][0] . "-$char" : $char;
    $previous = $char;
}
```

The boolean expression `(++$test == $previous || $test != $char)` will evaluate to int 0 or 1 when it is used with the `+=` operator.

The first part, `++$test == $previous`, tests that the previous character actually can be incremented. If it can't, then that character isn't an ASCII alphanumeric (the only characters affected by the `++` operator).

I initialized the range index `$i` to -1 because the first iteration will always increment it to 0.

Comment: Your answer is elegant and [holds up when given a more difficult mcve](https://3v4l.org/cDTLa).

Comment: Grr.  I was trying to do the incrementing trick right before bed last night and it didn't occur to me to just create another variable (`$test`) to prevent damaging the cached character.  Duh.  Anyhow, I can't see any way to improve/refine this answer.  Noice.

Comment: Actually after looking at the Q again, I think it might be simplified to just `$i += (++$previous != $char);`. I added that `$test` because I couldn't figure out another way to handle repeated non-alnum chars (to avoid getting things like "?-?"), but I just noticed the "Every character can only appear once" part, so maybe that's not necessary

Comment: I agree. https://3v4l.org/KcSIa

Comment: Beautiful! It works fantastic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because you're only allowing three "ranges" (`A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`). The algorithm has to keep track of whether the char you are up to is in one of those ranges, and if so whether it is the next sequential char in that range or whether it is a new character in the same range (which would result in a new range being started).

Here is code that produces the desired result, and also prints the tests being done at every step to determine whether to output a single character (e.g. `'?'`) or a range of characters (e.g. `'a-f'`).

```php
// Starting array:
$a = array('A','B','C','F','a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','o','q','!','?','0','2','3','4','9');

// Determine range that $ch is in and return an array with the start and end chars of that range, or an array of empty strings if no range.
function r( $ch ) {
    if (
        $ch >= 'A' && $ch <= 'Z'
    ) {
        return ['A', 'Z'];
    }

    if (
        $ch >= 'a' && $ch <= 'z'
    ) {
        return ['a', 'z'];
    }

    if (
        $ch >= '0' && $ch <= '9'
    ) {
        return ['0', '9'];
    }

    return ['', ''];
}

$b = []; // Destination array

// Determine starting range (if any):
$current_range = $ch_range = r($a[0]);
if ( strlen( $current_range[0] ) ) {
    $range_start = $a[0];
    echo "Current range is " . $current_range[0] . '-' . $current_range[1] . " (starting at $range_start)\n";
} else {
    echo "Not currently in a range\n";
}

echo "Starting loop\n";

for ( $i=1; $i < sizeof($a); $i++ ) {
    $ch = $a[$i];
    echo "Got $ch\n";
    $ch_range = r($ch); // Range that current char is in

    // Are we currently in a range?
    if ( strlen( $current_range[0] ) ) {
        // Are we still in a range?
        if ( strlen( $ch_range[0] ) ) { // Yes
            // Are we currently in the same range?
            if ( $ch_range[0] === $current_range[0] ) {
                // Are we at the next sequential char?
                if (
                    ord($a[$i-1])+1 == ord($ch) // We are at the next char in the range
                ) {
                    echo "We are at the next character in the range " . $current_range[0] . '-' . $current_range[1] . " (starting at $range_start) so doing nothing\n";
                } else {
                    echo "We are at a non-sequential character in the current range so adding [" . $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] . "] and starting a new range " . $ch_range[0] . '-' . $ch_range[1] . " (starting at $ch)\n";
                    $b[] = ($range_start == $a[$i-1]) ? $range_start : ( $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] );
                    $current_range = $ch_range;
                    $range_start = $ch;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Detected switch from range " . $current_range[0] . '-' . $current_range[1] . " to " . $ch_range[0] . '-' . $ch_range[1] . " so adding [" . $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] . "]\n";
                $b[] = ($range_start == $a[$i-1]) ? $range_start : ( $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] );
                $current_range = $ch_range;
                $range_start = $ch;
            }
        } else {
            // We were in a range, but no longer
            echo "We were in range " . $current_range[0] . '-' . $current_range[1] . " (starting with $range_start) but no longer, so adding range [$range_start-" . $a[$i-1] . "]\n";
            $b[] = ($range_start == $a[$i-1]) ? $range_start : ( $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] );
            $current_range = $ch_range;
            $range_start = $ch;
            
            // If not starting a range, add this ch:
            if ( ! strlen( $ch_range[0] ) ) {
                echo "Not starting a new range with '$ch' so adding [$ch]\n";
                $b[] = $ch;
                $range_start = '';
            }
        }
    } else { // We are not in a range
        // Are we starting a new range?
        if ( strlen( $ch_range[0] ) ) {
            echo "We are not in a range but starting a new one [" . $ch_range[0] . '-' . $ch_range[1] . "\n";
            $current_range = $ch_range;
            $range_start = $ch;
        } else {
            echo "We are not in a range and not starting one, so adding $ch\n";
            $b[] = $ch;
            $current_range = [];
            $range_start = '';
        }
    }
}

// Did we finish in the middle of a range?
if ( strlen( $range_start ) ) {
    echo "Finished in the middle of a range so adding [$range_start-" . $a[$i-1] . "]\n";
    $b[] = ($range_start == $a[$i-1]) ? $range_start : ( $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] );
}

print_r($b);

// Intended output: array('A-C','F','a-f','h-l','o','q','!','?','0','2-4','9')
```

There is one line of code which is repeated four times, and which could probably be refactored into a separate function:

```
$b[] = ($range_start == $a[$i-1]) ? $range_start : ( $range_start . '-' . $a[$i-1] );
```